# How to make my if statement work better in my tic tac toe program

Tags: c

My question is for the if statement under the "checks for duplicate move" section of the code. Sometimes the if statement works, but sometimes it just doesn't do it. The if statement is supposed to check the input from the user and compare it to the character currently in the coordinate. If the character is a 'X' or 'O' then it should not overwrite the character currently in that part of the array, tells the user it was an invalid move, and subtracts 1 from counter so it is still either X's or O's turn.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
struct coordinate{
    int i;
    int j;

};

//function that prints the tic-tac-toe board
int printTable( char array[3][3]){

    printf(" X's first O's second\n");
    printf("\n     0   1   2\n");
    printf("\n       |   |   \n");
    printf(" 0    %c | %c | %c \n", array[0][0], array[0][1], array[0][2]);
    printf("      ___|___|___\n");
    printf("         |   |   \n");
    printf(" 1    %c | %c | %c \n", array[1][0], array[1][1], array[1][2]);
    printf("      ___|___|___\n");
    printf("         |   |   \n");
    printf(" 2    %c | %c | %c \n", array[2][0], array[2][1], array[2][2]);
    printf("         |   |   \n\n");
    return 0;
}

int main (void){
    struct coordinate move;
    char game;
    int counter;
    char ttt[3][3] = {
        {'-', '-', '-'},
        {'-', '-', '-'},
        {'-', '-', '-'}
    };

    printf("\nWelcome to tic tac toe!\n");

    //Checks if you want to play
    printf("Would you like to play? y/n\n");
    scanf("%c", &game);

    //stops game by returning zero
    if(game == 'n'){
        printf("Have a pleasant day");
        return 0;
    }

    //starts game! =)
    if(game == 'y'){
        for(counter = 1; counter <= 9; counter++){
            printTable(ttt);

            //asks player where they want to move
            printf("Where would you like to move?");
            scanf("%i %i", &move.i, &move.j);

            //Checks for duplicate move
            if( ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'O' || ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'X' ){
                ttt[move.i][move.j] = ttt[move.i][move.j];
                printf("\n\n\nInvalid move. Try again\n\n\n");
                counter = counter - 1;
            }

            //O wins
            if( ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[0][1] == 'O' && ttt[0][2] == 'O' || ttt[1][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[1][2] == 'O' || ttt[2][0] == 'O' && ttt[2][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][0] == 'O' && ttt[2][0] == 'O' || ttt[0][1] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][1] == 'O' || ttt[0][2] == 'O' && ttt[1][2] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[2][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[0][2] == 'O'){
                printf("O WINS!!!!!");
                return 0;
            }

            //X wins
            if( ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[0][1] == 'X' && ttt[0][2] == 'X' || ttt[1][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[1][2] == 'X' || ttt[2][0] == 'X' && ttt[2][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][0] == 'X' && ttt[2][0] == 'X' || ttt[0][1] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][1] == 'X' || ttt[0][2] == 'X' && ttt[1][2] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[2][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[0][2] == 'X'){
                printf("X WINS!!!!!");
                return 0;
            }

            //X's turns
            if( counter == 0 || counter == 2 ||counter == 4 ||counter == 6 ||counter == 8){
                ttt[move.i][move.j] = 'X';
            }

            //Y's turns
            if( counter == 1 || counter == 3 ||counter == 5 ||counter == 7 ){
                ttt[move.i][move.j] = 'O';
            }

            //CATS GAME
            if( counter == 9){
                printf("Cat's Game =(");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. To get useful answers, please remove everything from your code that is unrelated to the question – but give us something that compiles. Ideally, that would leave something of maybe ten lines or fewer. Also, please do tell us what you expect to happen and what you see instead.

Comment: what is the use of this statement?  ttt[move.i][move.j] = ttt[move.i][move.j];

Comment: ttt[move.i][move.j] = ttt[move.i][move.j]; makes sure that the information currently in that part of the array stay the same....I think haha. I'm still pretty new to programming so I could have the wrong idea about what that would actually do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a 'continue' after the duplicate check (see below) so that your code doesnot do all the checking of who wins after a duplicate move. I believe this is the main source of your issue. However it could be more useful if you could elaborate little more what you meant by 'sometimes it works and sometimes it dont'

```
  if( ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'O' || ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'X' ){

                    printf("\n\n\nInvalid move. Try again\n\n\n");
                    counter = counter - 1;
                    continue;
                }
```

Comment: sorry I was being a little too vague. What I meant by that is that when I run the program it seems to check each move and makes sure not to overwrite any 'X's' or 'O's' that are already in the array. But at one point while I am testing for bugs it seems like the program skips that if statement and starts overwriting data if the user puts in a duplicate move. Was that more helpful?

Comment: then just try once with my suggestion of adding a 'continue'. When you say it skips, does it still print out "Invalid Move. Try again" or not?

Comment: That worked very well! Could you eplain to me why the data doesn't get overwritten by input by the user? Also what did the continue statement do that changed how it works?

Comment: @azmuhak That doens't solve the logic problem - the winner is still checked before the current cell was set.

Comment: @JC2120 continue statement makes the program counter go to the next iteration so it doesnot have to go through all the win lose if else.

Comment: @Constantin I know that the winner will appear on the next round but the problem OP was having was that his duplicate checking if statement was not working.

Comment: @Constantin You said there was a problem with the logic. Could you elaborate on what you mean?

Comment: @azmuhak so the continue statement will make it skip everything else inside of the for loop?

Comment: @JC2120 Yes, the continue statement will skip everything else in the current iteration inside the for loop (that means: it will jump to the head of the for-loop and continue with the increased counter variable from there on). The problems inside your logic are described in my answer here. Summarized: You're checking if there is a winner before you set the actual cell - so even if someone has won, there would be no winner output at this time. See my code to fix that problem (also the same problem resides even worse if the winner was decided in the last round - you won't get a winner this way).

Comment: @Constantin Ok that makes a lot of sense. Again I really appreciate your feedback everybody

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could just write that if it is Y's turn, the if statement could look like

```
if(counter%2 == 1)
```

and respectively for X's turn:

```
 if(counter%2 == 0)
```

What's more, this part of the code

```
//O wins
        if( ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[0][1] == 'O' && ttt[0][2] == 'O' || ttt[1][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[1][2] == 'O' || ttt[2][0] == 'O' && ttt[2][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][0] == 'O' && ttt[2][0] == 'O' || ttt[0][1] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][1] == 'O' || ttt[0][2] == 'O' && ttt[1][2] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[0][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[2][2] == 'O' || ttt[2][0] == 'O' && ttt[1][1] == 'O' && ttt[0][2] == 'O'){
            printf("O WINS!!!!!");
            return 0;

        }
//X wins
    if( ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[0][1] == 'X' && ttt[0][2] == 'X' || ttt[1][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[1][2] == 'X' || ttt[2][0] == 'X' && ttt[2][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][0] == 'X' && ttt[2][0] == 'X' || ttt[0][1] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][1] == 'X' || ttt[0][2] == 'X' && ttt[1][2] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[0][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[2][2] == 'X' || ttt[2][0] == 'X' && ttt[1][1] == 'X' && ttt[0][2] == 'X'){
        printf("X WINS!!!!!");
        return 0;

    }
```

could be arranged to be a function `checkWin(char c)`

by the way:

```
ttt[move.i][move.j] = ttt[move.i][move.j];
```

this line does nothing useful (it writes the value of an element to the same element so nothing changes) - you can simply delete this line

Comment: wow that's extremely helpful for that part of the program. Thanks! =)

Comment: But if I don't have that line wouldn't it overwrite the data already in the array?

Comment: also could you explain why and how the if statements you suggested work?

Comment: @JC2120 counter%2 means the rest of dividing counter by 2.  The rest in this case can be 1 or 0 . This means 'if counter is even ' or 'if counter is odd'.The % operator is quite common so you might want to remember that one ;) Good luck:-)

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues in your code - I will explain the one, that are not already pointed out by the other comments.

Your 'if' conditionals are very Long and confusing - you don't have to check against 'X' and 'O' respectively - you can just compare them and whatever result is hold there, it wins. However a Special check for '-' is needed, but it's easier maintainable in my opinion. However that's not the main Point here.

Your mistake was, that you checked if theres a winner BEFORE you actually set the current cell. so the winner would only appear one round to late. Consider the improved code (i also applied some of the improvements from the other comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct coordinate{
  int i;
  int j;
};

//function that prints the tic-tac-toe board
int printTable( char array[3][3]){
  printf(" X's first O's second\n");
  printf("\n     0   1   2\n");
  printf("\n       |   |   \n");
  printf(" 0   %c | %c | %c \n", array[0][0], array[0][1], array[0][2]);
  printf("    ___|___|___\n");
  printf("       |   |   \n");
  printf(" 1   %c | %c | %c \n", array[1][0], array[1][1], array[1][2]);
  printf("    ___|___|___\n");
  printf("       |   |   \n");
  printf(" 2   %c | %c | %c \n", array[2][0], array[2][1], array[2][2]);
  printf("       |   |   \n\n");
  return 0;
}


int main (void){
  struct coordinate move;
  char game;
  int counter, x, y;
  char ttt[3][3] = {
    {'-', '-', '-'},
    {'-', '-', '-'},
    {'-', '-', '-'}
  };
  printf("\nWelcome to tic tac toe!\n");
  //Checks if you want to play
  printf("Would you like to play? y/n\n");
  scanf("%c", &game);
  //stops game by returning zero
  if(game == 'n'){
    printf("Have a pleasant day");
  }else /*if(game == 'y')*/{   //starts game! =) 
    for(counter = 1; counter <= 9; counter++){
      printTable(ttt);
      //asks player where they want to move
      printf("Where would you like to move?");
      scanf("%i %i", &move.i, &move.j);
      //Checks for duplicate move
      if( ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'O' || ttt[move.i][move.j] == 'X' ){
        printf("\n\n\nInvalid move. Try again\n\n\n");
        counter = counter - 1;
        continue;
      }
      //X's turns
      if( counter % 2 == 0){
        ttt[move.i][move.j] = 'X';
      }else if( counter % 2 == 1 ){
        ttt[move.i][move.j] = 'O';
      }
      /* horizontal checks */
      for(x = 0; x < 3; x++){
        if(ttt[x][0] != '-' && ttt[x][0] == ttt[x][1] && ttt[x][1] == ttt[x][2]){
          printf("%c WINS!!!!!", ttt[x][0]);
          return 0;
        }
      }
       /* vertical checks */
      for(y = 0; y < 3; y++){
       if(ttt[0][y] != '-' && ttt[0][y] == ttt[1][y] && ttt[1][y] == ttt[2][y]){
          printf("%c WINS!!!!!", ttt[0][y]);
          return 0;
        }
      }
       /* diagonal checks */
      if(ttt[0][0] != '-' && ttt[0][0] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1]  == ttt[2][2]){
         printf("%c WINS!!!!!", ttt[0][0]);
         return 0;
      }else if(ttt[0][2] != '-' && ttt[0][2] == ttt[1][1] && ttt[1][1] == ttt[2][0]){
         printf("%c WINS!!!!!", ttt[0][2]);
         return 0;
      }
      if( counter >= 9){
        printf("Cat's Game =(");
        return 0;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I really like your vertical, diagonal, and horizontal checks. That makes the code much more readable. I really appreciate you writing up the edited version of my code.